# Navigating to different ViewControllers from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to IOS Objective C Programming. I am trying a very simple app. My main page is standard View Controller where i have a simple UITableView. What i am trying to do is to make a different view controller to come up when user select different cell on the Table View. Currently i populate 3 simple lines. I have searched for many historical discussion but can't seem to work (from segue options to simple instantiate view options). I give a snip of my code and hope that anyone can point me what i am doing wrong here.

[image: My code snippet]

Comment: your code is fine only one place is wrong , where u strcuk

Comment: are you using storyboard or xib in your project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: I am using storyboard

Comment: just wait , I update my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Storyboard**

Ensure one are you embed with `NavigationController` or `Not`, if Not,

just do the following way

`XCode menu` --> `Editor` --> `EmbedIn` --> `Navigation Controller`, do like

[image]

you get the output of

[image]

**Step-2**

In here we can navigate with two types

- **Connection Through**
- **Connection less**

**Connection Through**

[image]

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *SegName = @"";
   if (indexPath.row == 0)
   {
     SegName = @"firstSegumeName";
   }
   else if (indexPath.row == 1)
   {
    SegName = @"secondSegumeName";
   }
  else  if (indexPath.row == 2)
   {
     SegName = @"thirdSegumeName";
   }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SegName sender:self];

}
```

**Connection Less**

```
 if use `storyboard ID` with connection less
```

for example

[image: I have given segue identifier in SeconViewController as in the image.]

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIViewController *otherViewCon;
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
   {
      otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourfirstIdentifierName"];
   }
   else if (indexPath.row == 1)
   {
     otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yoursecondIdentifierName"];
   }
  else  if (indexPath.row == 2)
   {
      otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourthirdIdentifierName"];
   }


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik. I will review your post further. Many thanks again. Will post result tomorrow.

Comment: it works and this is the best answer i am looking for!

Comment: @hellochan -- welcome bro, if you additional help related to this I surely support you

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with segue names in the order in which you want to refer to the view controllers from your tableview and then in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

you can call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:[array valueAtIndex:indexPath.row sender:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**If its through XIB :**

```
Your_ViewController *vc = [[Your_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your_ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**If its through StoryBoard :**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
Your_ViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**If its through Coding :**

```
Your_ViewController *vc = [[Your_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

For Your questions :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Put above code here according to your requirement....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did try your suggestion, it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    firstViewController *u = [[ContactDetailsVC alloc]init];
    u= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace last 2 lines of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with:

```
UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
[self presentViewController:navC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, this do work. i am trying other suggestion as well.